# If $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous for $x \ge 0$, then it is bounded above by a straight line.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Explicitly: If $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous in $[0,+\infty)$, then there exists positive numbers $a, b$ such that $f(x) \lt ax+b$ for any $x \ge 0$.

Comment: Please consider updating your question with some information about what you have tried or where you are getting stuck. You will find people are much more willing to help if you do!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We write the definition of the uniform continuity:

$$\text{for}\; \epsilon=1\quad \exists\alpha>0\colon |x-y|\le\alpha \Rightarrow|f(x)-f(y)|<1$$

Now if $x\in[0,\alpha]$ we have $f(x)<1+f(0)$ and if $x\in [\alpha,2\alpha]$ we have $f(x)\le f(\alpha)+1<f(0)+2$ and so on by induction we find: if $x\in [n\alpha,(n+1)\alpha]$ we have $f(x)<f(0)+n+1$ but $x\ge n\alpha$ so $\frac 1 \alpha x\ge n$ and then
$$f(x)<n+f(0)+1\le \frac 1 \alpha x +(f(0)+1)$$
so take $a=\frac 1 \alpha$ and $b=f(0)+1$ and you have the desired result.

Comment: I'll do the same as Amy cause that happened to me likewise.