# Can we determine uniform continuity from graphs?

Tags: real-analysis, graphing-functions, uniform-continuity

Can we know from the graph of a function that whether the function is uniformly continuous or not? If the set on which the function is defined is not compact, so what one can say in that case?

Comment: If the function is defined on a closed interval and is continuous then it will be uniformly continuous but if the interval is not closed then what can we guess from the graph?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more specific. "Real Analysis (Uniform Continuity)" is extremely undescriptive, and redundant due to the existence of tags. See the edit on your first question for an example of good practice.

Answer (score 3):

If $f: [0,+\infty) \to \Bbb R$ is uniformly continuous, then there exists $A,B > 0 $ such that $|f(x)| \leq Ax + B $. In other words, the graph of an uniformly continuous function defined on the positive real numbers always stays under some line. For example,  $x^2$ defined in $[0,+\infty)$ is not uniformly continuous, just by seeing it.

Be aware of the reciprocal: the graph staying under a line does not mean that the function is uniformly continuous, take for example $\sin(1/x)$ or something like it.

This is a hard result to prove, but it is proved in some answer in this site. I'm browsing by the phone, so I don't have the link right now. I promise to find it and come back here with the reference.

**Edit:** [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/631353/if-fx-is-uniformly-continuous-for-x-ge-0-then-it-is-bounded-above-by-a-s) is the question I said above.

Comment: You can take $A=1/\delta $ where $\delta $ corresponds to $\epsilon=1$. Then $B=|f (0)|$.

Comment: Dear @IvoTerek, but if the interval is (-infinity, 0] then what about the graph?

Comment: Then you apply the result to $x\mapsto f(-x)$, it is still valid

Answer (score 1):

Here's a few sufficient conditions for uniform continuity that you should be able to recognize just by looking at a graph:

- The function continuous and defined on a compact set.
- The function is everywhere differentiable, and the derivative is bounded.
- The function is periodic.
- You can draw a two-sided cone (like an hourglass) of some fixed opening angle. If you place the point of this cone at any point on the function, the function stays outside this cone (this is in fact a necessary condition as well).

Comment: (nitpick) Do you need to include contiuity in your first condition?

Comment: I will add it. It is a fair nitpick!

Comment: @JahanClaes, would you explain this "If you place the point of this cone at any point on the function, the function stays outside this cone". What do you mean by "the point of the cone"? The cone will intersect the function at one point only i.e the aforementioned point of the cone?

Comment: I mean you have a two-sided cone, like an hourglass, opening upwards and downwards. You place the TIP of the cone (neck of the hourglass) at any point on the graph of the function. Then the function never enters the cone (never goes where the sand would be). Of course, I guess it technically intersects the cone at the tip, but I meant it never intersects the cone after that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about necessary and sufficient conditions, but if a function is differentiable with bounded derivative, or even just Lipschitz continuous, then it will be uniformly continuous. You can often see this type of thing by looking at the graph.