# Show the following for a uniformly continuous $f:\mathbb{C} \mapsto \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

Show for a uniformly continuous $f:\mathbb{C} \mapsto \mathbb{C}$ that there exists $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ so that the following is true

$$\forall z\in\mathbb{C}: |f(z)| \le \alpha\cdot|z|+\beta$$

I have written down the definition of uniform continuity, which is
$$\forall \epsilon \gt 0\ \ \exists \delta\gt0 \ \forall z,w\in\mathbb{C} \ \text{with} \ |w-z|<\delta : |f(w) - f(z)|<\epsilon$$
But that is as far as I got.

Any tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will take $\epsilon=1$ in the definition of uniform continuity.

By squeezing the $\delta$ a bit, we can assume that it is the $\leq$-inequality instead of $<$ and $2\delta$ instead of $\delta$.

So let us write $|w-z|\leq 2\delta$ implying that $|f(w)-f(z)|\leq 1$.

For $|w-\delta e^{i\theta}|\leq\delta$, $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$, then $|w|\leq|\delta e^{i\theta}|+\delta=2\delta$, so $|f(w)-f(0)|\leq 1$, so $|f(w)|\leq |f(0)|+1$.

For $|w-2\delta e^{i\theta}|\leq\delta$, $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$, $|f(w)|\leq|f(2\delta e^{i\theta})|+1\leq |f(0)|+2$.

For $|w-n\delta e^{i\theta}|\leq\delta$, $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$, $|f(w)|\leq |f(n\delta e^{i\theta})|+1\leq\cdots\leq|f(0)|+n$.

But for any $z$, some $n$ and $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$ are such that $|z-n\delta e^{i\theta}|\leq\delta$, then $n\delta-|z|\leq\delta$ and hence $n\leq (|z|+\delta)/\delta$, and that $|f(z)|\leq|f(0)|+n\leq |f(0)|+(|z|+\delta)/\delta$.

Comment: I think if you want to pitch this appropriately at the OP's level, you should point out that you are taking $\epsilon$ to be $1$ in the usual definition of uniform continuity.

Comment: This seems a bit beyond me. If it's not a big hassle to you, would you please try to explain step by step. Sorry

Comment: Perhaps you can read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/631353/if-fx-is-uniformly-continuous-for-x-ge-0-then-it-is-bounded-above-by-a-s) before looking at my solution. The philosophy is almost the same, just that in the real line you consider intervals but in the complex plane, you might have to consider annuli.

Comment: I'll take look at it and make some research myself and I'll report back.

Comment: @user284331 Sorry but I can't get my head around this. Is there another simpler way of achieving the same result ?

Comment: By the way do you understand the proof in the link provided?

Comment: I think I understand the math but not the concept.

Comment: Uniform continuous function behaves like a line at infinity, and it is also a classic exercise to show that, $x^{2}$ is not uniformly continuous.

Comment: I see, so all functions that have an increasing slope aren't uniformly continuous.

Comment: @Zntzozt: Not true! For instance, the hyperbola [$y=\sqrt{x^2+1}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3Dsqrt%28x%5E2%2B1%29) has an increasing slope, but is uniformly continuous.